# Delivering a Website as a Product

Tags: web, web-deployment

I apologize if this is a weird question but i can't really find good information regarding this.

I have a website that I would like to deliver as a product for other organizations to download and use within their organization. Much like Confluence or Wordpress. I know how they do it, they just package up their code and you can download it and deploy it yourself, however I'm just wondering what the other options are out there.

Is there a way to bundle up the entire site into an installer or create an image of some sort that can be downloaded and deployed. Ideally, I wouldn't want the customer to deploy the code and configure it themselves. It would be nice for them to just have to download something, run it and its up.

Any process or tool recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with confluence server, you still have to, at the minimum, configure a database, a home folder (for the product logs, plugins, cache), and the server itself to host the confluence product.

If you want to have the customer just use the product, then you should be hosting the whole product from your side and the customer can just create an instance for their company on your product (e.g. confluence cloud, Basecamp, workplace by facebook).

So, for these products that use the cloud solution, I only have to signup for an account, I don't need to handle any server side configuration or database as these are handled by your product hosting. But in the end it depends on what is your product and who are you targeting.

If you are targeting enterprise customers who do not want their data hosted in the cloud and want to have their own firewall, then you will need a server product. Nevertheless, these companies which have their own servers will also have IT admins who can handle the installation and configuration for your product as long as its well documented and easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that I was looking for is something like Docker. https://www.docker.com/

You can build a docker image that basically has all the prerequisites for your application built into it and you can deploy it across most machines that have docker install.